# NerdTree - Reveal file in tree

Tags: vim, nerdtree

Is there a shortcut which reveal the current file in the NerdTree directory panel.

Like TextMate  'Reveal file in Drawer' - Ctrl+Command+R

Answer (score 224, accepted):

in :h NERDTree:

```
:NERDTreeFind                                                  :NERDTreeFind
    Find the current file in the tree. If no tree exists for the current tab,
    or the file is not under the current root, then initialize a new tree where
    the root is the directory of the current file.
```

I don't think it's bound to anything by default, so you have to do a keybind yourself.

```
nmap ,n :NERDTreeFind<CR>
```

is what appears in my .vimrc, along with

```
nmap ,m :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
```

Comment: The keymapping works, but how to invoke NERDTreeFind within vim?

Comment: @toszter just `:NERDTreeFind`

Comment: Is there a way to set it to do this whenever the NERDTree is created within that tab?

Comment: @MrA you can just only create the NERDTree with the NERDTreeFind command - is that enough?

Comment: Is there a way to merge `:NERDTreeToggleVCS` and `:NERDTreeFind` ? I want reveal current file in the tree with parent being VCS parent

Answer (score 23):

Check this out, it automates the sync operation, whenever you change buffer, the nerdtree will automatically refreshed itself (I copied from [here](https://codeyarns.com/2014/05/05/how-to-highlight-current-file-in-nerdtree/) with tiny modifications)

```
" Check if NERDTree is open or active
function! IsNERDTreeOpen()        
  return exists("t:NERDTreeBufName") && (bufwinnr(t:NERDTreeBufName) != -1)
endfunction

" Call NERDTreeFind iff NERDTree is active, current window contains a modifiable
" file, and we're not in vimdiff
function! SyncTree()
  if &modifiable && IsNERDTreeOpen() && strlen(expand('%')) > 0 && !&diff
    NERDTreeFind
    wincmd p
  endif
endfunction

" Highlight currently open buffer in NERDTree
autocmd BufEnter * call SyncTree()
```

Comment: This config works well in most of the cases but it messed up everything when I used coc.nvim go to references functionality. using `BufRead` event in place of the `BufEnter` fixed the issue.

Comment: This opens a second NERDTree buffer when toggling it using `:NERDTreeToggle`.

Answer (score 9):

This should also probably be just a comment. With the current version toggling NerdTree and using SyncTree causes NERDTree to be invoked twice. This modification seems to fix that problem:

```
" Check if NERDTree is open or active
function! IsNERDTreeOpen()
  return exists("t:NERDTreeBufName") && (bufwinnr(t:NERDTreeBufName) != -1)
endfunction

" Call NERDTreeFind iff NERDTree is active, current window contains a modifiable
" file, and we're not in vimdiff
function! SyncTree()
  if &modifiable && IsNERDTreeOpen() && strlen(expand('%')) > 0 && !&diff
    NERDTreeFind
    wincmd p
  endif
endfunction

" Highlight currently open buffer in NERDTree
autocmd BufEnter * call SyncTree()

function! ToggleNerdTree()
  set eventignore=BufEnter
  NERDTreeToggle
  set eventignore=
endfunction
nmap <C-n> :call ToggleNerdTree()<CR>
```

Answer (score 4):

Chen Rushan's answer + the comment worked perfectly well for me, except when the tree is open. With this setting, the current file in the tree will be revealed when the tree is opened.

```
" Check if NERDTree is open or active
function! IsNERDTreeOpen()
  return exists("t:NERDTreeBufName") && (bufwinnr(t:NERDTreeBufName) != -1)
endfunction

function! CheckIfCurrentBufferIsFile()
  return strlen(expand('%')) > 0
endfunction

" Call NERDTreeFind iff NERDTree is active, current window contains a modifiable
" file, and we're not in vimdiff
function! SyncTree()
  if &modifiable && IsNERDTreeOpen() && CheckIfCurrentBufferIsFile() && !&diff
    NERDTreeFind
    wincmd p
  endif
endfunction

" Highlight currently open buffer in NERDTree
autocmd BufRead * call SyncTree()

function! ToggleTree()
  if CheckIfCurrentBufferIsFile()
    if IsNERDTreeOpen()
      NERDTreeClose
    else
      NERDTreeFind
    endif
  else
    NERDTree
  endif
endfunction

" open NERDTree with ctrl + n
nmap <C-n> :call ToggleTree()<CR>
```

Comment: Great!, I would like this script to have another feature also, if it s possible to collapse the other opened trees and open only tree for the current file, it would be more cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

```
function! NerdTreeToggleFind()
    if exists("g:NERDTree") && g:NERDTree.IsOpen()
        NERDTreeClose
    elseif filereadable(expand('%'))
        NERDTreeFind
    else
        NERDTree
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap <C-n> :call NerdTreeToggleFind()<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

To go along with Chen Rushan's post, the

```
autocmd BufEnter * call SyncTree()
```

won't let NERDTree close.  I couldn't find a solution (other than below) that would highlight the current open buffer in NERDTree while allowing NERDTree to Toggle.

Below is what I scraped together to be able to toggle NERDTree and have files highlighted while using `Ctrl + ]` for my next buffer mapping.

Hopefully others can improve this.

```
"Buffers
set hidden

function! IsNERDTreeOpen()        
  return exists("t:NERDTreeBufName") && (bufwinnr(t:NERDTreeBufName) != -1)
endfunction

function! NextBuffer()
     bnext
  if IsNERDTreeOpen() 
       NERDTreeFind
       wincmd p
  endif
endfunction

nnoremap <c-]> <Esc>:call NextBuffer()<CR>

function! PrevBuffer()
     bprev
  if IsNERDTreeOpen() 
       NERDTreeFind
       wincmd p
  endif
endfunction

nnoremap <c-[> <Esc>:call PrevBuffer()<CR>

function! ToggleNT()
    NERDTreeToggle
endfunction

map <c-u> <Esc>:call ToggleNT()<cr>
```